# vue-slick-carousel dots not showing properly

Tags: html, vue.js

When I run `yarn build` my nuxtjs application and see it on my browser, I don't see the dots properly from my carousel. Here's the image of how I see it:
[image]

To be precise, this is what it shows `â€¢`

I can see the dots in dev, they are dots with this content: `•`. Any ideas why is this happening?

My component:

```html
<template>
  <div class="mx-10">
    <VueSlickCarousel :dots="true">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <!-- <template #customPaging>
        <div class="custom-dot">
          <div
          class="rounded-full bg-black"
            style="width: 5px; height: 5px"
          ></div>
        </div>
      </template> -->
    </VueSlickCarousel>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueSlickCarousel from "vue-slick-carousel";
import "vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel.css";
import "vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel-theme.css";
export default {
  components: { VueSlickCarousel }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: Some code about this could be useful.

Comment: What if you build and start the project locally? Also, what do you have in the DOM on production? It's maybe an encoding issue?

Comment: When I run the server for the production build everything is okay, I can see the dots of the carousel. I don't see any meta tag for charset utf-8 though

Comment: What about the DOM? Can you compare locally and remotely? Also, did you tried in another browser?

Comment: I will compare local and remote headers. And yes, I tried in Brave and in Chrome for the local production project

Comment: Compare also the dots in the DOM, the ones locally and the ones which are broken mainly. Also, Chrome and Brave are 99% similar. Try something else Firefox and Safari (their engines are not `Blink` hence it will be more relevant).

Comment: I see one css file in the remote one that I don't have in the local one, but when I delete it it crashes all the styles and I can see the dots after that.

Comment: The only thing that changes for the dots is the `content` property, which should be the dot but it's the weird text

Comment: Check if there is no way to import your styling like `@import vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel.css;` in the `style` section as it will stay scoped to your component. Also double check that your dots are not over-written by any other CSS. Otherwise, you can also try another slider library since you don't have a lot of code with this one anyway.